# Intuition behind the definition of conditional probability: why $\textbf{P}(A\cap B) = \textbf{P}(A|B)\textbf{P}(B)$

Tags: probability

I have learned that the conditional probability is expressed as

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}$.

My teacher told us that given an probability of event, we can know the probability of consequence.

However, I do not get the intuition behind this formula.
Especially, why the joint probability is divided by  another probability?
So I want to know the essence of division of probability.

Comment: It might help to rewrite at it as $P(A, B) = P(A | B) P(B)$: the probability of the events $A$ and $B$ happening is equal to the probability that $B$ happens, times the probability that $A$ happens if $B$ happens.

Comment: As the "Related" column shows, this is a *hyper-* duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the idea underlying the conditioning $\textbf{P}(A|B)$ is to turn $B$ as the new sample space. Based on this, someone could propose the formula $\textbf{P}(A|B) = \textbf{P}(A\cap B)$ as the probability measure associated to the referred conditioning. However, if it was the case, we would have $\textbf{P}(B|B)= \textbf{P}(B)$, which not necessarily equals one. Since $\textbf{P}(A|B)\propto\textbf{P}(A\cap B)$, we must have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A|B) & = k\textbf{P}(A\cap B) \Rightarrow \textbf{P}(B|B) = k\textbf{P}(B\cap B) = k\textbf{P}(B) = 1\\\\
& \Rightarrow k = \frac{1}{\textbf{P}(B)}\Rightarrow\textbf{P}(A|B) = \frac{\textbf{P}(A\cap B)}{\textbf{P}(B)}
\end{align*}

which is the formula you have proposed.